# Pandas: assigning columns with multiple conditions and date thresholds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, portfolio

Edited:

I have a financial portfolio in a pandas dataframe df, where the index is the date and I have multiple financial stocks per date.

Eg dataframe:

```
Date    Stock   Weight  Percentile  Final weight
1/1/2000    Apple   0.010   0.75    0.010
1/1/2000    IBM    0.011    0.4     0
1/1/2000    Google  0.012   0.45    0
1/1/2000    Nokia   0.022   0.81    0.022
2/1/2000    Apple   0.014   0.56    0
2/1/2000    Google  0.015   0.45    0
2/1/2000    Nokia   0.016   0.55    0
3/1/2000    Apple   0.020   0.52    0
3/1/2000    Google  0.030   0.51    0
3/1/2000    Nokia   0.040   0.47    0
```

I created `Final_weight` by doing assigning values of `Weight` whenever `Percentile` is greater than `0.7`

Now I want this to be a bit more sophisticated, I still want `Weight` to be assigned to `Final_weight` when `Percentile is > 0.7`, however after this date (at any point in the future), rather than become 0 when a stocks `Percentile` is not `>0.7`, we would still get a weight as long as the Stocks `Percentile` is above `0.5` (ie holding the position for longer than just one day).

Then if the stock goes below `0.5` (in the near future) then `Final_weight would become 0`.

Eg modified dataframe from above:

```
Date    Stock   Weight  Percentile  Final weight
1/1/2000    Apple   0.010   0.75    0.010
1/1/2000    IBM     0.011   0.4     0
1/1/2000    Google  0.012   0.45    0
1/1/2000    Nokia   0.022   0.81    0.022
2/1/2000    Apple   0.014   0.56    0.014
2/1/2000    Google  0.015   0.45    0
2/1/2000    Nokia   0.016   0.55    0.016
3/1/2000    Apple   0.020   0.52    0.020
3/1/2000    Google  0.030   0.51    0
3/1/2000    Nokia   0.040   0.47    0
```

Everyday the portfolios are different not always have the same stock from the day before.

Comment: Have you got any attempted code to show us?

Comment: The code I wrote if very similar to PiRSquaredes answer below, however this only looks at one day ago, I wanted a nice pandas way to do it preferably without loops due to the dataset being huge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution is more explicit and less pandas-esque, but it involves only a single pass through all rows without creating tons of temporary columns, and is therefore possibly faster. It needs an additional state variable, which I wrapped it into a closure for not having to make a class.

```
def closure():
    cur_weight = {}
    def func(x):
        if x["Percentile"] > 0.7:
            next_weight = x["Weight"]
        elif x["Percentile"] < 0.5 :
            next_weight = 0
        else:
            next_weight = x["Weight"] if cur_weight.get(x["Stock"], 0) > 0 else 0
        cur_weight[x["Stock"]] = next_weight
        return next_weight
    return func

df["FinalWeight"] = df.apply(closure(), axis=1)
```

Comment: @MysterioProgrammer91 how much faster is this on the entire dataset? (for which you said it took around 3 days for the other answer).

Comment: @cronos Unless this is prey to the same issues that my submission had, which it might be, changing `closure` to just give indicator variables and then adding `df['Final Weight'] = df['Final Weight']*df['Weight']` after applying it should be faster, about 10% for me when I tested it.

Answer (score 3):

- I'd first put `'Stock'` into the index
- Then `unstack` to put them into the columns
- I'd then split `w` for weights and `p` for percentiles
- Then manipulate with a series of `where`

---

```
d1 = df.set_index('Stock', append=True)

d2 = d1.unstack()

w, p = d2.Weight, d2.Percentile

d1.join(w.where(p > .7, w.where((p.shift() > .7) & (p > .5), 0)).stack().rename('Final Weight'))

                   Weight  Percentile  Final Weight
Date       Stock                                   
2000-01-01 Apple    0.010        0.75         0.010
           IBM      0.011        0.40         0.000
           Google   0.012        0.45         0.000
           Nokia    0.022        0.81         0.022
2000-02-01 Apple    0.014        0.56         0.014
           Google   0.015        0.45         0.000
           Nokia    0.016        0.55         0.016
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the answer. I have amended the example dataframe in the question. I am actually not only looking at one shift, ie, after we buy the stock because its in the top 30 percentile, we will own it as long as it remains over 0.5 eg, can be even for 10 days. I would still assign a weight, but as soon as Percentile is below 0.5 it would not assign a weight to Final Weight and would wait till it is over 0.7 percentile again.

Answer (score 2):

One method, avoiding loops and limited lookback periods.

Using your example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


>>>df = pd.DataFrame([['1/1/2000',    'Apple',   0.010,   0.75],
                      ['1/1/2000',    'IBM',     0.011,    0.4],
                      ['1/1/2000',    'Google',  0.012,   0.45],
                      ['1/1/2000',    'Nokia',   0.022,   0.81],
                      ['2/1/2000',    'Apple',   0.014,   0.56],
                      ['2/1/2000',    'Google',  0.015,   0.45],
                      ['2/1/2000',    'Nokia',   0.016,   0.55],
                      ['3/1/2000',    'Apple',   0.020,   0.52],
                      ['3/1/2000',    'Google',  0.030,   0.51],
                      ['3/1/2000',    'Nokia',   0.040,   0.47]],
                     columns=['Date', 'Stock', 'Weight', 'Percentile'])
```

First, identify when stocks would start or stop being tracked in final weight:

```
>>>df['bought'] = np.where(df['Percentile'] >= 0.7, 1, np.nan)
>>>df['bought or sold'] = np.where(df['Percentile'] < 0.5, 0, df['bought'])
```

With '1' indicating a stock to buy, and '0' one to sell, if owned.

From this, you can identify whether the stock is owned. Note that this requires the dataframe already be sorted chronologically, if at any point you use it on a dataframe without a date index:

```
>>>df['own'] = df.groupby('Stock')['bought or sold'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0)
```

`'ffill'` is forward fill, propagating ownership status forward from buy and sell dates. `.fillna(0)` catches any stocks that have remained between .5 and .7 for the entirety of the dataframe.
Then, calculate Final Weight

```
>>>df['Final Weight'] = df['own']*df['Weight']
```

Multiplication, with `df['own']` being the identity or zero, is a little faster than another np.where and gives the same result.

**Edit:**

Since speed is a concern, doing everything in one column, as suggested by @cronos, does provide a speed boost, coming in around a 37% improvement at 20 rows in my tests, or 18% at 2,000,000. I could imagine the latter larger if storing the intermediate columns were to cross some sort of memory-usage threshold or there were something else involving system specifics I didn't experience.

This would look like:

```
>>>df['Final Weight'] = np.where(df['Percentile'] >= 0.7, 1, np.nan)
>>>df['Final Weight'] = np.where(df['Percentile'] < 0.5, 0, df['Final Weight'])
>>>df['Final Weight'] = df.groupby('Stock')['Final Weight'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0)
>>>df['Final Weight'] = df['Final Weight']*df['Weight']
```

Either using this method or deleting the intermediate fields would give result:

```
>>>df 
       Date   Stock  Weight  Percentile  Final Weight
0  1/1/2000   Apple   0.010        0.75         0.010
1  1/1/2000     IBM   0.011        0.40         0.000
2  1/1/2000  Google   0.012        0.45         0.000
3  1/1/2000   Nokia   0.022        0.81         0.022
4  2/1/2000   Apple   0.014        0.56         0.014
5  2/1/2000  Google   0.015        0.45         0.000
6  2/1/2000   Nokia   0.016        0.55         0.016
7  3/1/2000   Apple   0.020        0.52         0.020
8  3/1/2000  Google   0.030        0.51         0.000
9  3/1/2000   Nokia   0.040        0.47         0.000
```

For further improvement, I'd look at adding a way to set an initial condition that has stocks being owned, followed by breaking the dataframe down to look at smaller timeframes. This could be done by adding an initial condition for the time period covered by one of these smaller dataframes, then changing

```
>>>df['Final Weight'] = np.where(df['Percentile'] >= 0.7, 1, np.nan)
```

to something like

```
>>>df['Final Weight'] = np.where((df['Percentile'] >= 0.7) | (df['Final Weight'] != 0), 1, np.nan)
```

to allow that to be recognized and propagate.

Comment: This works but it takes around 3 days to run because of the number of stocks in my portfolio and due the the big data nature. Any way to make it faster?

Comment: Nice answer. But you can make this faster by using a single `FinalWeight` column from the beginning and work on it. No need to have 3 temporary columns.

Comment: @MysterioProgrammer91 Can you describe the internal structure of your dataset (# rows, # distinct stocks) and the environment you're running this in? I'm having some trouble constructing a scenario in which mine takes anywhere near that long while the dataframe on which it operates fits in memory, and that information would be a big help in figuring out where and how the techniques I currently go for fail to scale.

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

```
Dataframe:

             Stock  Weight  Percentile  Finalweight
Date                                               
2000-01-01   Apple   0.010        0.75            0
2000-01-01     IBM   0.011        0.40            0
2000-01-01  Google   0.012        0.45            0
2000-01-01   Nokia   0.022        0.81            0
2000-02-01   Apple   0.014        0.56            0
2000-02-01  Google   0.015        0.45            0
2000-02-01   Nokia   0.016        0.55            0
2000-03-01   Apple   0.020        0.52            0
2000-03-01  Google   0.030        0.51            0
2000-03-01   Nokia   0.040        0.57            0
```

**Solution**

```
df = df.reset_index()
#find historical max percentile for a Stock
df['max_percentile'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[df.Stock==x.Stock].iloc[:x.name].Percentile.max() if x.name>0 else x.Percentile, axis=1)
#set weight according to max_percentile and the current percentile
df['Finalweight'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Weight if (x.Percentile>0.7) or (x.Percentile>0.5 and x.max_percentile>0.7) else 0, axis=1)

Out[1041]: 
        Date   Stock  Weight  Percentile  Finalweight  max_percentile
0 2000-01-01   Apple   0.010        0.75        0.010            0.75
1 2000-01-01     IBM   0.011        0.40        0.000            0.40
2 2000-01-01  Google   0.012        0.45        0.000            0.45
3 2000-01-01   Nokia   0.022        0.81        0.022            0.81
4 2000-02-01   Apple   0.014        0.56        0.014            0.75
5 2000-02-01  Google   0.015        0.45        0.000            0.51
6 2000-02-01   Nokia   0.016        0.55        0.016            0.81
7 2000-03-01   Apple   0.020        0.52        0.020            0.75
8 2000-03-01  Google   0.030        0.51        0.000            0.51
9 2000-03-01   Nokia   0.040        0.57        0.040            0.81
```

**Note**

In the last row of your example data, Nokia's Percentile is 0.57 while in your results it becomes 0.47. In this example, I used 0.57 so the output is a bit different than yours for the last row.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to use the pandas.Series [rolling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) window method.

Perhaps something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

grouped = df.groupby('Stock')

df['MaxPercentileToDate'] = np.NaN
df.index = df['Date']

for name, group in grouped:
    df.loc[df.Stock==name, 'MaxPercentileToDate'] = group['Percentile'].rolling(min_periods=0, window=4).max()

# Mask selects rows that have ever been greater than 0.75 (including current row in max)
# and are currently greater than 0.5
mask = ((df['MaxPercentileToDate'] > 0.75) & (df['Percentile'] > 0.5))
df.loc[mask, 'Finalweight'] = df.loc[mask, 'Weight']
```

I believe this assumes values are sorted by date (which your initial dataset seems to have), and you would also have to adjust the `min_periods` parameter to be the max number of entries per stock.